# onRowSelect of radiobutton in Primefaces datatable

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, radio-button

I have a datatable using JSF2.0 where I have rows displayed with radiobutton

```
<p:dataTable id="dataTable" var="emp" lazy="true" value="#{req.lazyModel}"
            paginator="true" rows="10" 
            paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  
                    {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} 
           {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"
       rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10" 
           selection="#{req.selectedEmp}"
            rowKey="#{req.empNo}" 
       rowSelectListener="#{req.onRowSelect}">


 <p:column selectionMode="single" style="width:18px" />
```

and in Bean I have

```
public void onRowSelect(SelectEvent event) { 
       System.out.println("row "+((Request) event.getObject()).getEmpNo());  

    }
```

However `onRowSelect` method is not getting invoked. What could be the reason for this?

My idea of radiobutton is when user clicks radiobutton, I would like to display a datatable below the master datatable with details of selected row.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Update 1

```
<p:dataTable id="dataTable" var="emp" lazy="true" value="#{req.lazyModel}"
            paginator="true" rows="10" 
            paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  
                    {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} 
           {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"
       rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10" 
           selection="#{req.selectedEmp}">


 <p:column selectionMode="single" style="width:18px" />
 <p:ajax event="rowSelect" listener="#{reqMB.onRowSelect}" />
```

Comment: Your PrimeFaces version looks ancient, what is it?

Comment: @CagatayCivici I am using Primefaces 3.4.2.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There is no such attribute `rowSelectListener` in *Primefaces 3.4.2*

Use `<p:ajax event="rowSelect"` instead , like in the showcase

For radio/checkbox etc... these are the available `<p:ajax` event

- rowSelectRadio
- rowSelectCheckbox
- rowUnselectCheckbox
- rowDblselect

See the showcase (search for p:ajax on the page)
[DataTable - Selection](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/selection.xhtml)

Comment: Thanks Daniel for pointing it out. When I use `selectionMode="single"` without `<p:column selectionMode="single" style="width:18px" />` , then I could println statement in `onRowSelect` method. However if I use `<p:column selectionMode="single" style="width:18px" />`, then nothing is printed in  `onRowSelect` method. I have included the code as update 1 in my question.

Comment: then try to use `<p:ajax event="rowSelectRadio"`

Comment: I tried `<p:ajax event="rowSelectRadio" listener="#{reqMB.onRowSelect}" />`  , but no use. `onSelectRadio` doesn't seems to support.

Comment: I am using Hibernate 4, Spring 3 and JSF 2.0

Comment: I tried `rowSelectRadio`, but cannot get the prinln statement working in  `onRowSelect` method.

Comment: do you have any exceptions ? how about some simple `System.out.println("1 2 3");` ?

Comment: No exceptions and `System.out.println("1 2 3");` doesn't print. I am using lazy loading and datamodel is extended with `LazyDataModel`.

Comment: dunnoo... try with `rowKey="#{req.empNo}" ` in your table

Comment: I have added that as well, but no luck. I have put a wrong method like `listener="#{req.onRowSelectWrongMethod}"` in <p:ajax, however it didn't throw any errors.

Comment: +1 for `rowSelectRadio`, been searching it for hours

Comment: hi @Daniel  , stuck on the same issue how can I fire the event on select of <p:column selectionMode="single"  /> .. not working for me

Comment: @Rishi, adding `<p:ajax event="rowSelect"` to your `<p:dataTable` should work, like in the *Update 1* in the original question...

Comment: <p:column selectionMode="single" ></p:column>
                                        <p:ajax event="rowSelect" listener="#{managePatientTO.rowSelect}" 
                                             update="siteTable"
                                        /> and         
 public void rowSelect(SelectEvent event) {
  System.out.println(">><<>>");
 
 }  still not working  @Daniel

Comment: @Rishi, Is you table wrapper by `h:form` ? If it is wrapped and its not working you better post a new question with all the relevant details...

Comment: @Daniel  not wrapped in <h:from but why we use in primeface

Comment: @Rishi , your table must be wrapped in `h:form` , you can't use any ajax/basic submits unless its inside a `h:form`

Comment: 1 for rowSelectRadio, Work for me

Comment: If I could, I would upvote this every time, I landed here. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

**For older version of Primefaces.**

```
         <p:dataTable id="updateBanData"
                                 var="banSummary"
                                 value="#{sponsorBanMBean.sponsorBanForm.banSummaries}"
                                 styleClass="appTbl"
                                 selection="#{sponsorBanMBean.sponsorBanForm.selectedBanSummary}"
                                 emptyMessage="#{msgs.noRecordsFound}" selectionMode="single"
                    >



        <p:ajax event="rowSelect" listener="#{sponsorBanMBean.onUpdateBanRowSelect}"
                                update="updateSponsorShipBanDetailPanel"/>
    </p:p:dataTable>

     <p:outputPanel id="updateSponsorShipBanDetailPanel">
show your selection details. 

    </p:outputPanel>
```

**Java Code Inside Manged Bean.**

```
    public void onUpdateBanRowSelect(SelectEvent selectEvent) {
            logger.logMethodStartAsDebug();
            BanSummary selectedBanSummaryEvent = (BanSummary) selectEvent.getObject();

            if(selectedBanSummaryEvent != null){
                sponsorBanForm.setUpdateSponsorShipBanDetail(true);
            }
            logger.logMethodEndAsDebug();
        }
```